React: Dynamic color change every second
I need to write a function that will return either the color I specify or black every second. Right now, the color is set statically((cellStyle.backgroundColor = mapping.color)), but I need to make it dynamic. Could you please suggest how to implement this?
Example code:
export const Row = ({args}) => {
  ...
  const mapValue = (args) => {
    ...
    valueMappings.forEach((mapping) => {
      if (mapping.type === 'compare') {
            cellStyle.backgroundColor = mapping.color;
            cellStyle.color = 'black';
        }
      }
    });
    ...
  };
  const renderTableCell = (arg) => {
    ...
    let value = mapValue(arg);
    ...
    return (
      <div>...</div>
    );
  };
  return (
    <div>...</div>
  );
};


If I understood correctly what you want, you only need to add a setInterval and a useState for the background color:
export const Row = ({ args }) => {
 const [backgroundColor, setBackgroundColor] = useState('black');

 const mapValue = (args) => {
   let cellStyle = {};
   valueMappings.forEach((mapping) => {
     if (mapping.type === 'compare') {
        cellStyle.backgroundColor = mapping.color;
        cellStyle.color = 'black';
      }
    });
    return cellStyle;
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
      setBackgroundColor((prevColor) =>
        prevColor === 'black' ? mapValue(args).backgroundColor : 'black'
      );
    }, 1000);
    return () => clearInterval(intervalId);
  }, [args]);

  const renderTableCell = (arg) => {
    return (
      <div style={{ backgroundColor }}>
        {arg}
      </div>
    );
  };

  return <div>{renderTableCell(args)}</div>;
};

